# Normalizing variables after running apply gradients all within the optimizer class

Tags: python, tensorflow, math

So my question is how do I normalize the variables after I do gradient descent in the `_apply_dense()` method of the optimizer class. This is what I currently have.

```py
def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
    lr_t = math_ops.cast(self._lr_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    var_update = state_ops.assign_sub(var, lr_t*grad) 
    normalize = var.assign(tf.norm(var))
    return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_update,normalize])
```

My current code seems to just normalize the original variables without applying the gradient descent update. I know that this is due to the normalize step I have above which is just reassigning the original variables but normalized. How do I correct this so that the gradient descent step is applied and then the normalization is done on the result.

Comment: GD doesn't normalize variables. How do you want to normalize? l2? l1?

Comment: From my own experience, it's not the best idea to subclass the `tf.train.Optimizer` class. It is better to implement update operation separately. You may have problems using different `tf` versions this way.

Comment: I want to normalize the variables in the l2 norm after doing gradient descent.

Comment: After each gradient update step?

Comment: Yes, after each gradient step

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented as following:

```py
lr = 0.01
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    vars_ = tf.trainable_variables()
    grads = tf.gradients(loss_tensor, vars_)
    assign_ops = [tf.assign(v, (v - lr*g)) for g, v in zip(grads, vars_)]
    with tf.control_dependencies(assign_ops):
        vars_norms = [tf.sqrt(2*tf.nn.l2_loss(v)) for v in vars_]
        # next line prevents division by zero
        vars_norms = [tf.clip_by_value(n, 0.00001, np.inf) for n in vars_norms]
        update_ops = [tf.assign(v, v/n) for v, n in zip(vars_, vars_norms)]
    update_op = tf.group(update_ops)
```

Note that if I've added `tf.clip_by_value()` to prevent division by zero.

Here's a full usage example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None))

logits = tf.layers.dense(x, 2)

xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels=y, logits=logits)
loss_tensor = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)

lr = 0.01
with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    vars_ = tf.trainable_variables()
    grads = tf.gradients(loss_tensor, vars_)
    assign_ops = [tf.assign(v, (v - lr*g)) for g, v in zip(grads, vars_)]
    with tf.control_dependencies(assign_ops):
        vars_norms = [tf.sqrt(2*tf.nn.l2_loss(v)) for v in vars_]
        # next line prevents division by zero
        vars_norms = [tf.clip_by_value(n, 0.00001, np.inf) for n in vars_norms]
        update_ops = [tf.assign(v, v/n) for v, n in zip(vars_, vars_norms)]
    update_op = tf.group(update_ops)

# dummy data for illustration
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))
x_train = np.vstack([x_train, 2*np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))])
y_train = [0 for _ in range(10)] + [1 for _ in range(10)]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(10):
        loss, _ = sess.run([loss_tensor, update_op], feed_dict={x:x_train, y:y_train})
        print(loss)
# 0.7111398
# 0.7172677
# 0.71517026
# 0.713101
# 0.71105987
# 0.7090467
# 0.70706147
# 0.7051038
# 0.7031738
# 0.7012712
```

Comment: Hi Vlad. Thanks for the answer, but is there a nice way to implement it as an object from the Optimizer class?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do it? It depends for what purpose you going to use it